# USB drive stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive

My USB pen drive (A-data UE700 64GB) suddenly stopped working. I tested it on few PCs (every one with Linux) and it doesn't work on any of them. The device isn't even mounted. It used to work alright before.

I'd want to make it usable again, even if it comes to formatting it. Now I can't even format it, as the device doesn't show in /dev.

Here are few command outputs to help you grasp the situation. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

`$ fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 14593, w sumie sektorów: 234441648
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x000db573

Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   201062399   100530176   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       201064446   234440703    16688129    5  Rozszerzona
/dev/sda5       201064448   234440703    16688128   82  Linux swap / Solaris

UWAGA: Na '/dev/sdb' wykryto tablicę partycji GPT (GUID Partition Table)! fdisk nie obsługuje GPT. Należy użyć GNU Parteda.


Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 60801, w sumie sektorów: 976773168
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 4096
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 4096 / 4096
Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000

Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sdb1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partycja 1 nie zaczyna się na granicy bloku fizycznego.
```

`$ ls /dev/sdc`:

```
/dev/sdc
```

`$ lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 125f:de7a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05b Logitech, Inc. M-U0004 810-001317 [B110 Optical USB Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 125f:de7a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd.
```

`$ udevadm monitor --udev` (after inserting the drive into USB port):

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [6624.324399] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [6624.324724] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6624.324960] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20 (scsi)
UDEV  [6624.325246] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/scsi_host/host20 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [6625.313486] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [6625.313800] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [6625.314156] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/scsi_disk/20:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [6625.314531] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:48 (bdi)
UDEV  [6625.314777] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg4 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [6625.314810] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/scsi_device/20:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [6625.314968] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/bsg/20:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [6625.328241] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
UDEV  [6625.332452] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
UDEV  [6625.336298] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
```

Comment: Your setup looks OK on first glance, and if the USB drive doesn't show up **as device** on multiple systems, this is likely a hardware error. Even if it would come back (after shaking or twiddling its connector) I would not trust it with any data.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=<target device> bs=1M count=50`
And then do mkfs to it

Comment: @SHW Ok, so I did `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1M count=50`, then `mkfs /dev/sdc1`, but it doesn't seem to do anything other than creating some persistent file /dev/sdc1. Was I wrong in entering "target device" as /dev/sdc1?